# Xamarin Forms Listview in StackLayout Overlapping Layout Above It

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a ListView that I need stacked under another horizontal Stack Layout. No matter what I do, it appears that the ListView overlaps everything above it. I need it to not have this behavior and actually show the layout above. I just do not know how, and any help would be appreciated.

I've also attempted to put both in a grid, and did manage to free up space on the top but none of the Test labels show up, still.

[image]

As seen above, the ListView simply overlaps that which is above it (the stack layout with labels), as well as is shown with two entries above Aaron offscreen up top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="engME.YourFullNamesListPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Test 1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Text="Test 2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Text="Test 3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Text="Test 4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView x:Name="FullNamesList" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="50">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label FontSize="Large" 
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                       Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="F">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#cc0066"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="M">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#007acc"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="A">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#00994d"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Label.Triggers>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ShortMeaning}"
                                       FontSize="Small"
                                       TextColor="Gray"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="1">
                                </Label>
                                <Image Source="favorite.png"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="2"
                                       Scale=".7">
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: what is the version of your iPhone? I use the similar code but there is no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That StackLayout, that has a ListView inside it, you don't need it. Delete it and see what will happen.

Comment: Let me know if it helps.